# Interview: Making change for n cents (arbitrary denominations)

Tags: algorithm

This question occurred as part of an increasingly-difficult problem in an interview. It started ever so simply:

> (1) Assuming an infinite supply of coins (in the usual 1, 5, 10, 25 cent denominations). Given  *n* cents, is there always a way to make change for it using the normal denominations?

Yes, since the penny divides all possible values of *n* cents.

> (2) Good, now write a program that accepts *n* (positive) cents, and returns one possible way of making change for it

Return *n* pennies.

> (3) Smart ass. What if you want to minimize the number of coins required to make the change?

Start with the largest denomination *d_i*, and take the maximum number of them such that you don't exceed *n*, *m_i*. Take *n - (d_i)(m_i)* and repeat for next largest denomination.

> (4) Good, can you prove this solution is optimal?

Yes, { blah, blah }

> (5) Ok, *smirk* , now what if, in addition to the *n* cents, you were given an arbitrary-sized array consisting of arbitrary denominations? You can assume each denomination occurs only once in the array, and that all denominations are positive

My initial thought was just to sort the array of denominations, and apply the same logic as in (4). Luckily, before I communicated this, I caught myself and realized it wouldn't work. But now I realized I was in a pickle.

My next thought was to apply the sum-subset problem to each divisor of *n*, but realized this was probably overkill. The solution I ended up providing just used the [Change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem), and short-circuited it when I found *some* solution. I feel like there has to be a smarter way of doing this though..

The problem reduces to: **Given a finite set *S* of distinct natural numbers, find a linear combination of elements of *S* that (1) sum to another natural number *n*, (2) minimize the sum of coefficients in the lin.combination**

Comment: This is not a correct formalization of the original problem.

Comment: [This is](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

Comment: Feels very much like a dynamic programming problem. Wonder if the knapsack problem can reduce to this problem if the weights are all set to 0 for all the coins.

Comment: If all weights in knapsack are reduced to 0, then it will be solved greedily without dp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this problem has been studied as **Canonical coin systems**, and we even got a paper about how to determine whether a given coin system can support a greedy solution. The original paper may give you some insights: [Canonical coin systems for change-making problems](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.0400.pdf).

Alternatively, you can google the key word "Canonical coin systems" for more information.

Comment: And there it is! Perfect, thanks for the link.. should provide lots of good info!

Answer (score 0):

Let `d[pos][sum]` be the minimal number of coins required to make a change of `sum` money by using only first `pos`  denonimations or Infinity if it's impossible

Let `a[i]` be denonimation of coin i

It can be understood recursively. Rules `1)` and `2)` will be base of recursion.

1)`d[any pos][0]=0` (We can return no money in no coins)

2)`d[1][each sum]`= if (a[1]!=sum) Infinity else 1  (We can make a change of sum by one coin only if it has denonimation `sum`)

3)Else:

We may choose current point to make a change or not choose it

`d[pos][sum]=min(choose,d[pos-1][sum])` where

`choose=d[pos-1][sum-a[i]]` if sum>=a[i], Infinity otherwise

If we don't choose coin number pos, we try to make the same change with pos-1 coins. Hence, `d[pos-1][sum]`

If we choose coin number pos, then we only have to make a change for sum that is less than current by denonimation of pos. `d[pos-1][sum-a[i]]`

But we can choose coin number pos only if it's denonimation is less or equal to the current sum

---

In actual solution

a)Recursion should be replaced by cycle

or

b)We should store `was[pos][sum]` - if the value `d[pos][sum]` was counted.

When we try to count `d[pos][sum]`

if `was[pos][sum]==true` just return it. (The value is already counted)

else: count it according to steps 1-3 and set `was[pos][sum]` to true

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy answer that gives you pseudo-polynomial time and space in terms of n (i.e. running time and memory use that is proportional to n instead of the input size which is log n), and a more difficult but more useful answer that can get you to true polynomial time for fixed denominations.

Make an array A of size n. This array stores the minimum number of coins needed to make k cents for each k = 1 to n, where A[k] = -1 if it is impossible to make k cents. You can fill in this array sequentially from k = 1 to n, by recording A[k] = 1 if k is one of your denominations, and otherwise recording A[k] = M + 1 where M is the minimum of A[k - C] over all denominations C (and A[k] = -1 if all k - C are either not positive have or A[k - C] = -1). Then, once you reach n, you can go back through the array starting at n and subtracting each denomination to see which denomination gave you the optimal answer, tracing back through all the coins used to form the optimal solution.

That's the easy answer. Now, the hard answer for very large n compared to the denominations is figuring out when you can take a short-cut and just take the largest denomination coin for a while until the total remaining cents gets down to below some value. I don't know how to solve for that value, but it is possible, and the value always exists, and once you figure it out then it doesn't matter how big n is, all you have to do is compute how many of the largest coin to use first (O(log n) time), and then solve once you are below the value (constant time if you consider the denominations fixed, or running time that depends on the denominations (but not n) if the denominations aren't fixed).

Comment: "figuring out when you can take a short-cut" A crude bound is that, if the largest denomination is D cents, the other denominations should not be used more than D - 1 times. A better bound is to look at the A array and stop after it's optimal D' times in a row to use the D-cent coin next, where D' cents is the next largest denomination.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thank you, I'll leave this as a comment instead of editing my answer, because people may have other ways to quickly estimate the bound too, which they can leave as comments. You are ever insightful as always. =)